# this is true?$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\varliminf E(f_{n}\le c+\frac{1}{k})=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\varlimsup E(f_{n}\le c+\frac{1}{k})?$

Tags: real-analysis

If 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)(x\in E)$$ is exsit,

prove or disprove
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\varliminf E(f_{n}\le c+\dfrac{1}{k})=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\varlimsup E(f_{n}\le c+\dfrac{1}{k})?$$

where $$E(f_{n}\le c+\dfrac{1}{k})=\{x\in E,f_{n}(x)\le c+\dfrac{1}{k}\}$$

I can't  take counterexample,so maybe is true?

But I can't explain why is true?

Thank you for you help

Comment: What is $E(f_n\leq c+\frac1k)$? Is it $\{ x\in E;\; f_n(x)\leq c+\frac1k\}$?

Comment: @Etienne,yes,that's mean ,

Comment: You should put $f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ and consider the set $\{ x\in E;\; f(x)\leq c\}$.

Comment: Hello,@Etienne,and then ? Thank you

Comment: Then you have to think a little bit... I'm pretty sure that you will the solution. Try to compare this new set with the other two.

Comment: @Etienne,sorry,I can't understand you method? can you post full you solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since chinamath insisted, here is a detailed answer.

Set $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}$ and  $A:=\{ x\in E;\; f(x)\leq c\}$. Let us show that the two sets considered above are both equal to $A$.

Since obviously $\underline A:=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \liminf_n \{ x;\; f_n(x)\leq c+\frac 1k\}$ is contained in $\overline A:=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \limsup_n \{ x;\; f_n(x)\leq c+\frac 1k\}$, it is enough to show that $A\subset\underline A$ and $\overline A\subset A$.

Take any $x\in\overline A$. Then, for each fixed $k$, there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $f_n(x)\leq c+\frac1k$, by the definition of "$\limsup$". Since $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that $f(x)\leq c+\frac1k\cdot$ This being true for every $k\geq 1$, we conclude that $f(x)\leq c$, i.e. $x\in A$.

Now, let $x\in A$. Then, for each fixed $k$ we have $f(x)<c+\frac1k\cdot$ Since $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, it follows that one can find $n_0(x)$ such that $f_n(x)<c+\frac1k$ for every $n\geq n_0(x)$. So $x\in \liminf_n E(f_n\leq c+\frac1k)$, by the definition of "$\liminf$"; and since this is true for every $k$, this gives $x\in\underline A$.